# Multiple lines on a single plot from dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need to plot the average budget of films separated by genre over time. I have a pandas dataframe with the columns `Genre`, `Year` and `Average Budget in Millions`. I am able to get the data to plot with one graph for each genre, but I haven't been able to get the plots to all fall on the same graph. Here is the code I'm using to get the multiple graphs.

```
for g in all_genres:
    plotgenre = refineddata[refineddata['Genre'].str.contains(g, na=False)]
    plotgenre.plot(kind='line',x='Year',y='Average Budget in Millions', label = g)
```

Comment: Hi welcome to SO, please add some sample data so we can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the figure and axis first and use them to create the plot:

```
np.random.seed(42)
all_genres = ['crime', 'romantic']
refineddata = pd.DataFrame({'Average Budget in Millions':np.random.normal(size=20),
                          'Year':range(20), 'Genre':np.random.choice(all_genres, 20)})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(6,4))
for g in all_genres:
    plotgenre = refineddata[refineddata['Genre'].str.contains(g, na=False)]
    plotgenre.plot(kind='line',x='Year',y='Average Budget in Millions', label = g, ax=ax)
```

[image]

But it is even easier if you can use the [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/) library:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.lineplot(data=refineddata, x='Year', y='Average Budget in Millions', hue='Genre')
```

[image]